# Noise isolation for 'vanilla' engine

Tags: engine

Is it possible to add silicon or other soft devices between the engine of an old car and the chassis, in order to reduce the amount of noise that is transmitted and thus the amount of vibration felt in the car ?

Additionally, how to high-end cars (like BMW 7 Series?) reach near 0-noise ?

Answer (score 2):

Adding any type of engine dampening between the chasis and engine  would not be cost effective. You may be able to quiet the interior noise level with the addition of sound absorbing material to the floor under the carpet. Luxury vehicles reduce the noise levels by adding insulation to the body and isolating the engine from the chasis with special motor mounts. Additionally the engines themselves run smoother. Some makers have incorporated noise canceling technology in the vehicle. It is sometimes refered to as "white noise". It is a sound that is emitted at a specific frequency and volume that cancels out the noise the vehicle generates. The result is reduced noise.